# There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 1,Token line offset = 13,Token in error = Transaction ]

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

While passing Insert Query im getting error.

> There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 1,Token line offset = 13,Token in error = Transaction ]

Below is the actual query

```
var SQLINSERT = "INSERT INTO Transaction ([Exchange_Id],[Broker_id],[Trade_Date],[Settlement_No],[Settlement_Date],[Scrip_id],[Buy_Sell],[Quantity],[Rate],[Gross_Amt],[Brokerage],[Service_Tax],[Ttc],[Stamp_Duty],[Stt],[Net_Amt],[Final_Rate]) VALUES (@0,@1,@2,@3,@4,@5,@6,@7,@8,@9,@10,@11,@12,@13,@14,@15,@16)";

db.Execute(SQLINSERT,DExchangeid,DBrokerName,DTradeDate,DSettlementNo,DSettlementDate,DScripName,DBuySell,DQty,DRate,DGrossAmt,DBrokerage,DServiceTax,DTtc,DStampDuty,DStt,DNetAmt,DFinalRate);
```

I am using Microsoft Webmatrix Razor Syntax
Provider : .NET Framework Data Provider for Microsoft SQL Server Compact 4.0

Answer (score 12):

Transaction is a reserved word.  If that is your table name use `[Transaction]`